# PHP - Login Form to Show Data From Database

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms, undefined

I'm making a project. There are 4 files: `loginMHS`, `manageLoginMHS` (optional), `inputPerwalian`, `db`.

In `db`, the program will connect to database. This is the code:

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", NULL, "perwalian");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    die("Connect Error : " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
?>
```

In `loginMHS`, user should input their NRP (varchar) & password. This is the code:

```
<?php
session_start();
?>

<form action="manageLoginMHS.php?act=login" method="POST">
    NRP: <input type="text" name="unrp"/><br />
    Password: <input type="password" name="upass"/><br />
    <input type="submit" value="LOGIN"/>
</form>
```

I use `manageLoginMHS` just as a helper file. NRP & varchar from `loginMHS` will be checked. If user doesn't input NRP, the program show message "Input perwalian belum dapat diakses saat ini". Do I really need this file? Or, I can use only 2 files (`loginMHS` & `inputPerwalian`)?

```
<?php
require './db.php';
session_start();
$act = $_GET['act'];

switch ($act) {
    case "login":
        $nrp = $_POST['unrp'];
        $pass = $_POST['upass'];

        $sql = "select * from mahasiswa where nrp = '" . $nrp . "'";
        $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

        if(isset($_POST['unrp'])){
            if(empty($nrp)){
                echo "<br /> Input perwalian belum dapat diakses saat ini"
                    . "<br />";
            }
            else {
                header('Location: inputPerwalian.php');
            }
        }

        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            if($pass == $row['password'] && $nrp == $row['nrp']) {
                $_SESSION['login'] = TRUE;
                header("Location: inputPerwalian.php");
            }
            else {
                echo "Invalid Password";
            }
        }
        else {
            echo "User not found";
        }
        break;
    default:
        die("Unknown");
}
?>
```

Then the program will show data in `inputPerwalian` from database, which have the same NRP & varchar. This is the code:

```
<?php
session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['login'])) {
    require './db.php';

    //echo $_POST['unrp'];

    //$nrp = $_POST['unrp'];
    //$pass = $_POST['upass'];

    $sql2 = "select nrp, nama, jatah_sks, foto_profil from mahasiswa"
        . " where nrp=".$nrp; //this line is the error
    $result2 = mysqli_query($link, $sql2);
    if (!$result2) {
        die("SQL Error " . $sql2);
    }
    while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) {
        echo "NRP: " . $row2['nrp'] . "<br />";
        echo "Nama: " . $row2['nama'] . "<br />";
        echo "SKS Maks: " . $row2['jatah_sks'] . "<br />";
        echo "Sisa SKS: " . "<br /><br />";
    }
}   
?>
```

I have these errors:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: nrp in C:\xampp\htdocs\ProjectUAS\inputPerwalian.php on line 37
SQL Error select nrp, nama, jatah_sks, foto_profil from mahasiswa where nrp=
```

So, the program won't show data from database which I have selected before.

What should I do to fix those errors? Please explain your answer. Thank you.

Comment: If the last block of code is from a different function or page, you haven't defined $nrp in that scope before you try to use it.  That causes $nrp to be undefined, which then causes the error in your SQL statement.

Comment: @SgtAJ I don't understand. Which part that is wrong?

Comment: You said you have 4 forms.  Is each in a different file?  Is the code block with the error in a file with one of the other blocks of code you showed, or in its own file?

Comment: @SgtAJ What I mean is, 4 files. Sorry, I don't understand your question

Comment: In the file with the error, you don't define $nrp.  You must assign $nrp a value before you use it.  The only line where you tried to assign it a value is commented out:  `$nrp = $_POST['unrp']`.  Where does $nrp get its value?

Comment: @SgtAJ I used it before. But, the result is, I got more errors. So, I commented it

Comment: You still have to give $nrp a value before you use it in a query.  If you have other errors, you will need to fix those.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113086/discussion-between-grace-michelle-and-sgt-aj).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be easier to do this with 2 files (or 3 if you want your database connection in a separate file)

You could merge your LoginMHS and ManageLoginMHS pages like this:

```
<?php
  session_start();

  require './db.php';

  if (isset($_POST['act']))
  {
    $act = $_POST['act'];

    switch($act)
    {
    case "login":
    $nrp = $_POST['unrp'];
    $pass = $_POST['upass'];

    $sql = "select * from mahasiswa where nrp = '" . $nrp . "'";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

    if(isset($_POST['unrp'])){
        if(empty($nrp)){
            echo "<br /> Input perwalian belum dapat diakses saat ini"
                . "<br />";
        }
        else {
            header('Location: inputPerwalian.php');
        }
    }

    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        if($pass == $row['password'] && $nrp == $row['nrp']) {
            $_SESSION['login'] = TRUE;
            $_SESSION['nrp'] = $nrp;
            header("Location: inputPerwalian.php");
        }
        else {
            echo "Invalid Password";
        }
    }
    else {
        echo "User not found";
    }
    break;
    default:
    die("Unknown");
    }
    }
  }
?>

<form action="" method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="act" value="login" />
  NRP: <input type="text" name="unrp"/><br />
  Password: <input type="password" name="upass"/><br />
  <input type="submit" value="LOGIN"/>
</form>
```

This combines all login to one form.  It sets nrp in a session variable you can read from any other page, so your inputPerwalian page can check it like this: `$nrp = $_SESSION['nrp'];`

Comment: Also, you should never echo actual PHP or database errors to the screen in a production environment, as it could expose your database schema or PHP code to visitors.  It is better to echo a basic error message like `echo 'Database connection failed.  Please try again or notify a system administrator is this problem persists.';` and log the actual error somewhere you can check it later.